# Autocmd is breaking my lsp and not working (neovim)

Tags: neovim, autocmd, lsp

I’m new to neovim so there’s a decent chance this is just a rookie mistake. I wanted to make an autocmd to remap F5 to running the (python) file. I found a stack overflow post on how to do this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948491/running-python-code-in-vim) but that was for vim. I tried my best to translate if for neovim using some other tutorials I found (and doing my best at understanding docs), what I came up with is this:

```
local api = vim.api
local RunFile = api.nvim_create_augroup("RunFile", { clear = true })

api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    "FileType",
    {
        callback = "map <buffer> <F5> :w<cr>:exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>",
        pattern = "python",
        group = RunFile,
    }
)
```

however when I include the file in my init.lua, not only does it not work (the autocmd doesn’t even show up when looking in `:au FileType`, let alone run) it also makes the text a boring white and when I try to format, it gives the error `[LSP] Format request failed, no matching language servers.` while I definitely do have the language server (it works when the autocmd file is not included in init.lua). I’m probably just making some simple mistakes, but I cannot for the life of me find what I’m doing wrong. Does anyone here have any suggestions?
For the record, I use lsp zero and treesitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
local api = vim.api
local RunFile = api.nvim_create_augroup("RunFile", { clear = true })

api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    {"FileType"},
    {
        pattern = {"python"},
        command = "map <buffer> <F5> :w<cr>:exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>",
        group = RunFile,
    }
)
```

If you use a Vim `command` in your `autocmd` you shoul use the `command` keyword instead of the `callback` keyword that is for a Lua function.

Comment: That fixed the issue, thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) Welcome to Vim!